# how to create a multiple tab on a single view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razorengine

I have to create an MVC view where I have 3 tabs on a page.
Each tab has 10 fields to be accepted from the user. Then, the second tab is proceeded to which also has 10 fields.

My question is this: If I click on the back button of the page or if I go to the previous tab from the second tab, then it should show all the data which is filled by user and how to create a multiple tab on a single view. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code that we can see?  By back button of the page I'm assuming you mean the browser back button?  You say that if someone clicks the (browser) back button or navigates from the second tab of your form to the first tab you want to display the data entered by the user?  How do you want to display the data?

I'm having trouble understanding and I imagine other people will.  If you would like help with your problem then you will have to update your question with more information.

Comment: And if you want to create a multiple tab on a single view then I believe this should be asked as a separate question again with more information.

Comment: It’s not browser back button it’s a button on page named as previous which will available on 2nd tab which will redirect you to 1st tab.
and about the data its same as a form that I have to fill all three tabs input filed and after that I can only submit  my data but before submitting if I want to change the data of 1st tab then the data should be available over there which is field by user.

Comment: I hope my question is clear to all... I didn’t started code yet.

Comment: Are you asking "How do you ensure that the fields on all 3 tabs have been completed?"  and if the fields have not completed then are you asking "How do you take the user to the first tab that has not been completed?"?